# Understanding lambda function sorting

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

I`m solving some problems in Python, I didn't know how to solve so I looked up in the solution,and saw the usage of lambda, I know how it works basic, but here so complex to understand, could please someone explain me what's going on?

For the example we have this dict:

```
d = {'000000000': 156, '255000000': 228, '255255255': 228, '000255000': 228}
return sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]))[0][0]
```

It returns: 000255000

**And also :**

```
d = {(0, 0, 0): 156, (255, 0, 0): 228, (255, 255, 255): 228, (0, 255, 0): 228}
return sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0][0],x[0][1],x[0][2]))[0][0]
```

It returns: `(0, 255, 0)`

Comment: I can't give a good answer but I'll recommend [this blog post](https://medium.com/@happymishra66/lambda-map-and-filter-in-python-4935f248593) and [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp)

Comment: I think you are looking for `min`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: (-x[1],x[0]))
```

returns this

```
[('000255000', 228), ('255000000', 228), ('255255255', 228), ('000000000', 156)]
```

Basically, it just sorts the key, value by treating them as a tuple (-value, key).

Answer (score 0):

To understand code like that, split it up into its components and take a look at the individual results you get. That way, you can follow what part of the code does what and you will be able to understand it easier:

```
>>> d = {'000000000': 156, '255000000': 228, '255255255': 228, '000255000': 228}
>>> key = lambda x: (-x[1],x[0])
>>> for x in d.items(): print(x, key(x))

('000000000', 156) (-156, '000000000')
('255000000', 228) (-228, '255000000')
('255255255', 228) (-228, '255255255')
('000255000', 228) (-228, '000255000')
```

So `d.items()` apparently iterates through the key-value pairs of the dictionary. And the lambda is a function that, when called with that key-value pair, returns a transformed value.

That value is then used to sort the result:

```
>>> result = sorted(d.items(),key=key)
>>> for x in result: print(x)

('000255000', 228)
('255000000', 228)
('255255255', 228)
('000000000', 156)
```

Because the `key` function is only used to sort the items, the actual items of the result are still the original key-value pairs of the dictionary.

The first `[0]` then gets the first item from the result, i.e. the smallest item. And the second `[0]` gets the *key* from that key-value tuple:

```
>>> result[0]
('000255000', 228)
>>> result[0][0]
'000255000'
```

In your second example, there is the same thing going on. It’s just that the key function is a bit more complex:

```
>>> d = {(0, 0, 0): 156, (255, 0, 0): 228, (255, 255, 255): 228, (0, 255, 0): 228}
>>> key = lambda x: (-x[1],x[0][0],x[0][1],x[0][2])
>>> for x in d.items(): print(x, key(x))

((0, 0, 0), 156) (-156, 0, 0, 0)
((255, 0, 0), 228) (-228, 255, 0, 0)
((255, 255, 255), 228) (-228, 255, 255, 255)
((0, 255, 0), 228) (-228, 0, 255, 0)
```